# Php. Не могу подключиться к БД Mssql (sqlsrv)

Tags: php, laravel, sql-server

SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server to communicate with SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver for SQL Server for x64: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Решил установкой ODBC драйвера на Windows